# How to Define date format from a given date

Tags: date, datetime, sas, formatting

I wanted to know, how can we define date format from given date

for example, i have date 20180423 then in sas I want to define format as 'yyyymmdd'

similarly , i have date given in data as 12022018 then i want to define as 'ddmmyyyy'

Please note that, date is provided to me in proper date, but i want to define format now.
Date given may be different in future
so I need to take care all of the date format through SAS

What I thought was given date 20180422
use substr function

```
data test;
a=20180422;
a=substr(a,1,4);
b=substr(a,5,1);
c=substr(a,7,1);
run;
```

but not sure.

If anyone can provide the solution,then it really helps me in my project work.

Thanks in Advance for help.

Comment: The `anydtdte` informat will try to convert many different types of strings into date values.  Be careful as whether it defaults to M-D-Y or D-M-Y order of ambiguous strings depends on the locale setting.

Comment: what happens if your date comes something like `20180404`? How do you judge which is month and which is date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `input(a,anydtdte20.)`; this will convert any date to SAS date, then use the functions `Year()`, `Month()`, `Day()` to extract the data you want.
You will find this SAS [Post](https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2016/11/11/anydtdte-informat-read-any-date-sas.html) very useful about dates and locales.

Solution:

I created a table with two rows; each row have a different date format YYYYMMDD & DDMMYYYY to show you how the code will handles different date formats, saved them to SAS date and broke them down to Year, Month & Day:

```
options DATESTYLE=DMY;
data have;
input a;
datalines;
20180422
12022018
;
run;

data test;
set have;
format date_a date9.;
date_a=input(a,anydtdte20.);
Year_a=year(date_a);
month_a=month(date_a);
day_a=day(date_a);
run;
```

Output:

```
a=20180422 date_a=22APR2018 Year_a=2018 month_a=4 day_a=22 
a=12022018 date_a=12FEB2018 Year_a=2018 month_a=2 day_a=12
```

[image: Output]

Comment: will try using this, thanks for your help. in 2nd date 12022018' would be ddmmyyyy right but here month shows 12 , actually date_a should show 12 right?

Comment: If your date locale is setup to US it will be read as MMDDYY if Locale is Europe it will be read as DDMMYY. I will add an options statement in my code to use DMY locale.

Comment: thanks you guys for your help, suppose I have date formats with / also and -(hyphen) too. What I am thinking is to save date_format  in file ddmmyyy,mmddyyyy,yyyymmdd,dd/mm/yyyy,yyyy/mm/dd,mm/dd/yyy, and 1 date format have timestamp to yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss will have colon in hh:mm:ss , I had stored above date_formats in 1 table along with their length now, in .txt file i have given date for ex 2018-06-23 then automatically it should pick up yyyy-mm-dd from table, if 20180406 then yyyymmdd. Could you please help me with this

Comment: Please put this in a new question.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want to convert various values to a date.  SAS stores dates as a number, being the number of days since 1st Jan 1960.  It's then usual to format this number to display as a date, in whichever format is preferred.

When importing dates that's are already in a format, it is necessary to use the `input` function, along with an informat, to convert the formatted value to a SAS date.  If the date values being read in are all in the same format, then the specific informat can be used.  In your case, where different formats are used, you can use the `anydtdte.` informat which will convert most of the standard date formats to a SAS date.

The example below converts 3 different date formats to a SAS date, then displays the SAS date in the `date9.` format.  I've printed both the unformatted and formatted new values to the log, just so you can see they are stored as numbers.

```
data _null_;
input date_in $20.;
date_out = input(date_in, anydtdte20.);
put date_in date_out date_out :date9.;
datalines;
20180422
12022018
27apr2018
;
run;
```

Comment: thanks for reply, I think it will format all dates to date9. specific format,so it means 20180422 automatically converts to yyyymmdd. , 12022018 automatically converts to ddmmyyyy. and last date 27apr2018 converts to date9., In short from given date (i am importing date from .txt file) for example 20180424 with column name  DT is present in .txt file then now i need to check first 4 digit is year only Also , if different date present in .txt file like 20122018 here first 2 digit is 'dd' , 'mm' and 'yyyy' so from given date I need to define format . so here format is completely changed

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand you.  The above code will convert both the numbers you've stated to a valid SAS date.  You don't need to know beforehand what format they're in when you import them

Answer (score 0):

You can use an if condition inside a data step. Using If condition, check for the condition to be true (check date value satisfies the required criteria), then format the date using a put function.Put function can take a source as first argument and format as second argument , and return the formatted value. Different values of same column,  can have different formats specified that way.

Something like this,

```
  if a = 'date1CheckCondtion' then newA = put(a , dateformat1.);
  if a = 'date2' then newA = put(a , dateformat2.);
```

You may then choose to get all values in a common format  like this:

```
  dateA=input(newA,mmddyy6.);
```